# Search feature with Parse.com Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to search all the users in my parse database, either their username or name. So far it's searches but doesn't recognize the first letter... It only starts searching after the second letter has been typed, and once it has been typed it then searches for the first letter...

Here's my query, if anyone can see the problem I'd love your help!

Any more explanation just drop a comment... Many thanks.

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let usernameQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    usernameQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    usernameQuery.limit = 20
    usernameQuery.whereKey("username", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + self.searchBar.text!)
    usernameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects!.isEmpty {

                let fullnameQuery = PFUser.query()
                fullnameQuery?.whereKey("firstname", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + self.searchBar.text!)
                fullnameQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {
                        self.search.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                       for object in objects! {

                            let name = SearchStruct(username: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
                            fullname: object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String,
                            profileImage: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
                          self.search.append(name)
                        }
                        self.tableView1.reloadData()

                    }
                })
            }

            self.search.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in objects! {
                let user = SearchStruct(username: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
                fullname: object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String,
                profileImage: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)

                self.search.append(user)
            }
            self.tableView1.reloadData()
            textLabel.text = ""
            self.activityS.stopAnimating()
        }
    })
```

**EDIT**

So I removed the code above and added this:

```
 func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
       // let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        //Here the spinnier is initialized

        activityS.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        activityS.startAnimating()


        let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        textLabel.text = "Searching for \(searchBar.text!)"


        self.view.addSubview(activityS)
        self.view.addSubview(textLabel)


        let usernameQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        usernameQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        usernameQuery.limit = 20
        usernameQuery.whereKey("username", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + searchController.searchBar.text!)
        usernameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if objects!.isEmpty {

                    let fullnameQuery = PFUser.query()
                    fullnameQuery?.whereKey("firstname", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + searchController.searchBar.text!)
                    fullnameQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {
                            self.search.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                            for object in objects! {

                                let name = SearchStruct(username: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
                                    fullname: object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String,
                                    profileImage: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
                                self.search.append(name)
                            }
                            self.tableView1.reloadData()

                        }
                    })
                }

                self.search.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {
                    let user = SearchStruct(username: object.valueForKey("username") as! String,
                        fullname: object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String,
                        profileImage: object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)

                    self.search.append(user)
                }
                self.tableView1.reloadData()
                textLabel.text = ""
                self.activityS.stopAnimating()
            }
        })
        // Do your search and refresh the table
        tableView1.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: I suggest downloading all of the objects in the view did load. Then filter them as the user searches.

Comment: This could be some serious overhead depending on how many entries he has...

Comment: @penatheboss I don't think that would be a good approach as there could be alot of users....

Comment: @KevinGoedecke Yeh, that's mainly why I did It this way

Comment: Why don't you use ````updateSearchResultsForSearchController```` of the ````UISearchResultsUpdating```` protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol. `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` will then be triggered every time you enter something into the search bar.

```
class YourTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    // Initiate the searchController
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Use the current view controller to update the search results and as delegate
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
    ...
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        // Do your search and refresh the table
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer... Would that be instead of (searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange)?

Comment: Yes, just access the searched text with ````searchController.searchBar.text````.

Comment: So this should be like this then: usernameQuery.whereKey("username", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + searchController.searchBar.text)   ?

Comment: Yes, I hope you implemented ````UISearchBarDelegate```` protocol?

Comment: Yes I have, I added the code I have now above.. But when I try to search nothing happens

Comment: Sorry I forgot you have to set the ````searchResultsUpdater```` delegate. See edited post.

Comment: Oh ok, mm it doesn't recognize searchController in ViewDidLoad. What is that exactly?

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchController/initWithSearchResultsController:  also see my edit

Comment: I initiated the UISearchController as you mentioned above but still nothing...What If I used the func searchBar textDidChange?

Comment: No you really want to use the Protocol, thats what's intended for. An other part that you might have forgot is adding the searchController to the Table? I included it into my original post as well.

Comment: Ok, I think it's not telling the searchBar or something.. I added it programatically like this var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    and then customized it in the ViewDidLoad

Comment: The searchController comes already with a SearchBar, if you add an other one then it won't work. Try this tutorial here: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/